# implecations of fetching and decoding two instructions simultaniously

Tags: architecture, parallel-processing, pipeline, cpu-architecture, instructions

Instruction is fetched and decoded one at a time usually per cycle.

I was wondering what are the implications if we fetch and decode 2 instructions simultaneously. What would be the changes in the architecture that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

The idea that instructions are fetched and decoded one at a time per cycle is generally not true.

Let's get some simple things out of the way.  You can have multiple cores, and those cores each run independently.  That's the primary way that Intel, etc. are increasing the number of instructions per cycle (IPC).  You also have simultaneous multithreading (hyperthreading in intel speak) where you have two independent threads running on the same core.  This is another way that has been common to increase the IPC over the last decade (Sun's Niagara chip had lots of threads.)

Ok, now for the answer you probably really want.  Within a single thread of execution, most modern processors can fetch and decode multiple instructions per cycle (this is usually called super-scalar).  Pretty much all modern high-performance processors do this.  The exception is very low power processors and those that explicitly sacrifice single thread performance for throughput (Niagara, which uses lots of threads)

Now for the architectural changes (there are zillions of options).  The biggest breakdown is whether you have a fixed length instruction (ARM) or a variable length one (x86).

With fixed length instructions, you know what the instruction boundaries are, so it's relatively easy to build a system that can fetch say 8 instructions per clock and decode all of them.  Usually, your fetch width is bigger than your execution width because you're going to have branch instructions and the fetch is likely to be aligned whereas the branch can land you anywhere.  In these systems, the biggest challenge is really getting the branch predictor (really it's a next block of instructions predictor) working well.

With variable length instructions, it's simply a world of pain.  In the x86 world, these days, they translate those variable length "macro" instructions into (mostly) fixed width "micro" instructions.  Then you can store those micro instructions in a special cache (often called a trace cache).  If for a particular address, you get a hit in the trace cache, then you don't have to decode the macro instruction and you can simply deal with micro instructions.  (Trace caches can do a lot more and can be used on fixed width machines too since you can play tricks like realign blocks or even put together sequential sequences of instructions that include taken branches, hence the name "trace").  Even with this trace cache approach, you still need to try to fetch more than one macro instruction per cycle if you want to get high performance.  Usually systems can do a few and they essentially use predictors to indicate what the instruction boundaries are likely to be.

Most of the really complicated stuff is only found on out-of-order processors since it generally doesn't make much sense to try to do more than two instructions in parallel in an in-order machine since hazards and dependencies just happen too often to make anything more practical.